# overwrite ion-nav-bar with ion-header-bar in one page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

i am tryng to show ion items with ion header bar having default ion nav bar.

The problem is, i want ionic bar header in one page rather than ionic nav bar. i tried with below but no luck.

Below from index.html

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-light  bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-back"></ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
```

Below from one page:

```
<ion-view title="items" id="page15" >
  <ion-content  ng-controller="itemsCtrl"  class="has-header"  hide-nav-bar="true">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-minus-outline"
        ng-click="data.showDelete = !data.showDelete"></button>
    </div>
    items
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button button-icon icon ion-log-out" ng-click="test()">
      </button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-list show-delete="data.showDelete" >
      <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" 
        item="item"
         class="item-remove-animate">
         {{ item.name }}
        <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" 
          ng-click="onItemDelete(item)">
        </ion-delete-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
  <div class="float-button" ng-click="additem()">
    <span class="height-fix">
     <a class="content">
      <i class="ion-ios-plus-empty"> </i>
     </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</ion-view>
```

The output is coming as below

[image]

i dont want the default ion nav bar n that page and want only ionic header bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it finally. Just add nav bar buttons instead of ionic header bar.